# Get Python Turtle to return coordinates of mouse click

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

How do I get Python Turtle to return the coordinates of a mouse click so that it can be used in a different function?  I have this code:

```
import turtle as t

def main():
    while True:
        t.onscreenclick(t.goto)
        x=t.xcor()
        y=t.ycor()
        print(str(x) + ', ' + str(y))
        t.mainloop()

 main()
```

I'm making a game where I want you to be able to click on the screen where you want to go, so for that, I was hoping to be able to use t.onscreenclick() to give me the coordinates of where the mouse was clicked, and be able to send those coordinates to another function, but this code only returns (0.0, 0.0) and no other coordinates no matter how many times I click.

Any help would be appreciated, this is my first attempted at making any sort of game using python, thanks.

Comment: `t.mainloop()` does not return until the window is closed, so you don't really have a loop here.  You should do your `print` (and whatever else you want to be triggered by a click) from within the function you pass to `t.onscreenclick()` - it will receive two parameters with the X and Y coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You've completely misunderstood turtle event handling.  I suggest you (re)read the documentation before you proceed.   Although the introduction to turtle uses `t.onscreenclick(t.goto)` as an example, it's a very noisy handler so you're better off writing your own that disables the handler first, does the `goto()` and reenables the handler.  Below is what I believe you're trying to implement:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

def my_handler(x, y):
    screen.onscreenclick(None)  # disable handler inside hander
    turtle.goto(x, y)
    print(turtle.position())
    screen.onscreenclick(my_handler)

turtle = Turtle()

screen = Screen()

screen.onscreenclick(my_handler)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry I don't think I was specific enough, for what I want to do I need to be able to click on a spot then use the coordinates in another function to find the value at that spot. For instance, I would like to get the points from where they clicked and use them in a calculator function along with other parameters. If you don't understand what I'm saying let me know, I'm new so this is probably confusing sounding.